# URL rewrite to remove parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a site where all the pages are actually index.php + a 'name' parameter that is analyzed
and loads the appropriate template and content.
the homepage url is:
**http://www.some_site.com/?page=homepage**

**1.** i was asked to "change" the homepage url to:
**http://www.some_site.com**
can i use url rewite and htaccess for that and if so, what should i write there?

working on my local machine, i tried this code (mode rewrite is enabled):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /index.php /index.php?page=homepage
</IfModule>
```

i would still need the  'name' parameter to be available to the php code of course, so i can load the
template and css files.

**2.** it would be nice for other pages (not homepage) to  be converted from (example)
**http://www.some_site.com/?page=products**
to:
**http://www.some_site.com/products**
this is less crucial.

thanx in advance and have a nice day :-)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a rewrite rule at all. Just change your index.php file to show the homepage when there is no page variable at all.

```
if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $_GET['page'] = 'homepage';
}
```

For educational purposes, the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule /$ index.php?page=homepage [L]
```

That is, the URI to match is just the slash (the URI starts after your domain in the URL). The `$` means that there should be no characters after the slash.

As for products and such, assuming single words made of only letters:

```
RewriteRule /([a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should be what you're looking for (for your second, less crucial, question). Put it in your `.htaccess`-file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-z0-9-_]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1
```